# jQueryUI datepicker('setDate') removes time

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

is it a bug in jQuery UI? When I call `.datepicker('setDate', date);` and `date` is a date-object with time, datepicker set the time of `date` to 0:00?

And if I clone the variable..

```
var datewithtime = new Date();
var lTmpDate = datewithtime;
$('#Modal_KalendarTermin #DP_DatumVon').datepicker("setDate", lTmpDate);
```

.. `datewithtime` is just the same (without time - only date with time = 0:00).

I found a third parameter "noChange" in the [jquery-ui.js](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.4/jquery-ui.js) -> serach for "`_setDate: function`". For what?

<sub>Excerpt from jquery-ui.js</sub>

```
/* Set the date(s) directly. */
_setDate: function(inst, date, noChange) {
    var clear = !(date);
    var origMonth = inst.selectedMonth;
    var origYear = inst.selectedYear;
    date = this._restrictMinMax(inst, this._determineDate(inst, date, new Date()));
    inst.selectedDay = inst.currentDay = date.getDate();
    inst.drawMonth = inst.selectedMonth = inst.currentMonth = date.getMonth();
    inst.drawYear = inst.selectedYear = inst.currentYear = date.getFullYear();
    if ((origMonth != inst.selectedMonth || origYear != inst.selectedYear) && !noChange)
        this._notifyChange(inst);
    this._adjustInstDate(inst);
    if (inst.input) {
        inst.input.val(clear ? '' : this._formatDate(inst));
    }
},
```

Thanks for your answers and sorry for my bad english!

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery UI datepicker only deals with dates. As you can see from the code you've linked to, the date being passed to `setDate` is only used to set the values of `currentDay`, `currentMonth` and `currentYear`. All other date info will be dropped, by design.

The `noChange` parameter is a flag, probably only used internally, to determine whether or not to call `notifyChange` when the values are changed.